# nodejs uncaught ECONNABORTED socket exception

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm making an IMAP server in nodejs and ran into a behavior that puzzles me.

Basicaly, Thunderbird sends a command (logout) to which (according to the RFC) :

> The server MUST send a BYE untagged response before the (tagged) OK response, and then close the network connection.

Except TB don't seems to wait for the last command and disconnect right after the BYE response which raise a `write ECONNABORTED` exception.

I'm, of course, listening to `error` on the client (and server) socket, and that error never makes it to the listener.

If I plug into the socket write callback, the error is indeed present and the same that is raised :

```
socket.write(data, (err) => {});
```

With :

```
process.on("uncaughtException", (err) => { });
```

I get the exception, and if I don't rethrow it, `socket.on("close", hadError => {})` get called with hadError set to true. Yet, `socket.on("error")` still don't get called.

I found a two-part workaround :

1. made the socket write calls into a Promise so that I can catch the error at the proper place
2. silently drop this exception from the uncaughtException listener.

That workaround seems wrong on many levels :

- an unexpected client disconnection seems a pretty standard scenario in socket communication and thus should be catchable somewhere. I would have thought that adding a try/catch clause around the socket.write would be the perfect place, but experience proved my theory wrong
- silencing all socket write errors due to ECONNABORTED in uncaughtException without any way of knowing if that's acceptable or not seems a bit too lenient

So how/where am I supposed to catch that exception ?

Answers not solving my issue :

- [Trying to catch error when writing to socket using Node JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808907/trying-to-catch-error-when-writing-to-socket-using-node-js) : I'm already listening to on(error) and nothing comes up. Also, exception is raised before on('end').
- [Node.js uncaught socket exception- socket is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735285/node-js-uncaught-socket-exception-socket-is-closed) : try/catch don't catch anything and `socket.writable` is `true`, `socket.destroyed` is `false` just before writing
- [Gracefully handle uncaught exception in forked process with a socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34776853/gracefully-handle-uncaught-exception-in-forked-process-with-a-socket) : I'm not forking anything

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a bug in nodejs - I've seen it in other cases too. An approach I've adopted is:

```
// When your nodejs program initializes...
let onErr = err => {
  if (err?.suppressed) return; // Ignore suppressed errors
  console.log('Uncaught error', err);
  process.exit(0);
};
process.on('uncaughtException', onErr);
process.on('unhandledRejection', onErr);

// ... later on ...
try {
  await doThingThatCausesError(...);
} catch (err) {
  if (isUnexpectedError(err)) throw err;
  err.suppressed = true;
  handleExpectedError(err);
}
```

This pattern allows us to "opt-in" to suppressing certain errors; ignoring only specific errors at a global level seems safe to me.